# How to keep a reference to a systemd unit without enabling

Tags: systemd

I want to keep a reference to a systemd service but I don't want the service started at boot (enabled). I also don't want to use the RemainAfterExit attribute because then when the service has exited if I start the unit it won't start, instead I'll need to restart it to start it, which is confusing.

I want some way to tell systemd: keep watching this unit but don't enable it.

So the output of `systemctl show-units --all foo.service` would show that the unit does exist but it isn't running:

```
# systemctl list-units --all foo.service
UNIT        LOAD   ACTIVE   SUB  DESCRIPTION
foo.service loaded inactive dead foo.service

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

The reason I want to know if the unit is running or not is because then I my monitoring system knows:

- the unit is installed
- but it's not running

Comment: It seems that just skipping the "remain after exit" attribute, and not enabling the service, should give you what you want.  Did you try that?  What happened?

Comment: By skipping the RemainAfterExit attribute do you mean not using it? If we don't use remainafterexit and don't enable it then systemd loses a reference to the unit and the unit doesn't show up in the `systemctl list-units -a` command

Comment: So, what you want to know is if there is a unit file?

Comment: I want to know if it is (loaded and running) or (loaded and stopped) or (was never loaded) but when checking `systemctl list-units -a` there's no difference between (loaded and stopped) and (was never loaded) because the unit doesn't show up in both cases